# Number of search results not counting accurate

Tags: search-results

Our search result page shows 50123 result on search result page 1, 49567 on page 2, 48945 on page 3, 50327 on page 4 and on and on.

This causes confusion on our users, and they wonder about it. Why does it differ?

Comment: My wild guess is that SharePoint to save performance only estimates the total number of results for the query. And the closer you get to the end of the results list, the more accurate this approximation becomes. I have thought about checking out exactly how this works behind the scenes, but I have not gotten the time.

Comment: @RobertLindgren you are right. Write up your response as the answer.

Comment: I have done accordingly @MatthewMcDermott :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My (not so) wild guess is that SharePoint to save performance only estimates the total number of results for the query. And the closer you get to the end of the results list, the more accurate this approximation becomes.

I have thought about checking out exactly how this works behind the scenes, but I have not gotten the time.

Comment: We had reported similar case to Microsoft and the answer we got is that it is by design.

Comment: thanks Robert and Sudhir . I was struggling to find out an answer for this.